# footer with z-index of -1 sits above section with z-index of 1?

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I have a tucked footer with a z-index of -1 and its layered over my stats section. This is the section that shows the company's stats. I have this section with a z-index of 1 and the footer still is above it when scrolling ? I've read z-index on CSS tricks but can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.inner-wrap {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

header {
 background-image: url(img/wall2.jpeg);
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

.logo, ul {
 flex-basis: 30%;
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

li:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.phrase {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
}

.phrase p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.phrase a {
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 25px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Bitter';
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.phrase a:hover {
 background-color: #cc2900;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.phrase .fas {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

/*---ABOUT---*/

.stats {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px grey;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.stats div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.stats p {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.stats div:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 2px;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.60);
}

.about .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('img/concrete.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

.about h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 4rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 word-spacing: 7px;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

.underline {
 width: 100px;
 height: 2.5px;
 background-color: red;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: -15px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

.about p {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer-window {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: transparent;
}

.footer {
 z-index: -1;
}

.footer .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 height: 500px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Kane Concrete And Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="inner-wrap">
  <header>
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <ul>
      <li class="after">Home</li>
      <li class="after">About</li>
      <li class="after">Services</li>
      <li class="after">Job Openings</li>
      <li class="after">Gallery</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   
   <div class="phrase">
    <p>It all starts at the foundation.</p>
    <a>Get a Quote</a>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
   </div> 
  </header>

  <section class="stats">
   <div id="start-year">
    <p>Established</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">2015</p>
   </div>

   <div id="projects">
    <p>Projects</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">200+</p>
   </div>

   <div id="claims">
    <p>Insurance claims</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">87%</p>
   </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <div class="underline"></div>

    <p><span style="color: red;">W</span>e believe that Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum doloremque impedit laudantium magnam eos quae ipsum, rem, dolorum saepe laboriosam ipsam nobis architecto debitis, vel aut provident tenetur perferendis, aliquid commodi magni sequi hic quia nemo! Nam odio fugiat, similique eum saepe. Laboriosam officiis delectus reiciendis, est tenetur voluptates ducimus! Ducimus enim dolor, eos id porro, amet culpa alias sunt reprehenderit necessitatibus deserunt eum. Sunt quia accusamus facilis quo, cum maiores nam illum sit quisquam, tempora fugit? Quod voluptate debitis voluptatum illo. Est, rerum sequi. Corporis atque incidunt placeat aliquam error veniam quis, minus voluptatem, qui, a pariatur voluptatibus, ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe labore aliquid magnam velit, nisi consequuntur!</p>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>

 <section class="footer-window"></section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia deleniti praesentium ipsam aliquam fugiat, nihil explicabo voluptas quod incidunt non consectetur, aperiam ad quae, quos, odit consequuntur saepe a fuga recusandae voluptatibus reiciendis ipsa. Dolore ad distinctio aut, tempore ducimus odit reprehenderit perferendis vero assumenda a voluptates commodi corrupti alias illo voluptas laudantium veniam repudiandae temporibus adipisci quaerat eum, qui consequuntur nihil? Est assumenda, aut excepturi voluptas in ipsa necessitatibus adipisci dignissimos. Omnis, similique nam hic iure atque possimus voluptatibus reiciendis dignissimos eaque repudiandae pariatur eveniet sint. Nulla, aspernatur. Nobis est pariatur voluptates, unde laboriosam officia, dolore quis magnam ipsa.
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On your snippet, the footer is actually behind the section, the z-index works like expected. I think you are confused by the background color of the footer, but that's because the stats section does not have a background color, if you set it to white you'll see it's above the footer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, u need to:

```
.footer.wrapper {
  some code
}
```

There is an extra space between `.footer` and `.wrapper`. A space means to target both elements, no-space means the child of, if i'm correct.

I hope it was that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the space means grab any child within .footer that has the class name .wrapper

Comment: You are right, sorry. I thought that was what you needed, like what is in this pen. [PEN](https://codepen.io/sebaLinares/pen/MLeeJG?editors=1100).